# Parsley js validation is not removed when condition is satisfied

Tags: jquery, parsley.js

I have an application which uses parsley js. One of the form has a Inputbox along with a jquery datepicker.
The validations work fine when data is not entered, the issue is for input as soon as a value is entered the validation message goes away but same does not happen for the date picker. I found the same issue on their site for checkbox and radiobutton

[image]

does anybody have a workaround for this.

I am not adding my code here since its just a required attribute to my inputbox and jquery datepicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a browser bug whereby an `input` event is not always fired when it should. Parsley now [circumvents it](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/issues/1080)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will keep a eye on that.